# Is it possible to alter base for relative urls for a subset of DOM tree via JS without iterating elements?

Tags: javascript, html

In my web app, I have some pieces of html content (or rather markup converted into html) with relative references (to links, images, iframes etc). The content is federated, so some `<img src="subfolder/img.jpg" />` can be broken in the context of a page with another path (say, `<img src="../subfolder/img.jpg" />` would work correctly in some context).

I wonder if such content can be "repaired" on the DOM basis, meaning that relative paths are calced differently for different parts of DOM (so I want to set one "base" for one container and another "base" for another).

Sections 5.1.2 and 5.1.3 [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970917/htmlweb.html) describe in a nice and simple way how relative URLs are resolved into absolute ones (use `base` element, if present; otherwise use an HTTP header if present; otherwise use). But this regards static html. I need to understand what happens with dynamic html generation ([rfc1808](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1808) doesn't seem to be clear regarding the dynamic case, too).

I've tried the following code

```js
document.head.innerHTML += "<base href='"+
      document.location.protocol+"//" + document.location.host +
      "/subfolder/' />";

var container = document.querySelector('.loaded_from_subfolder');
container.innerHTML = 'some text and an <a href="test.html">added link</a>';
/* or
var newLink = document.createElement('a');
newLink.setAttribute('href','test.html');
newLink.innerHTML = "added link";
container.appendChild(newLink);
*/
```

```html
<a href="adjacent_page.html">initial link</a>
<div class="loaded_from_subfolder"></div>
```

in hope that the absolute url is already calced for the `<a href="adjacent_page.html">initial link</a>` and the new base will only be applied to the newly generated one. However, the url is changed for the first link as well.

So is there a way to change the "base" of urls in a container with JS, or the only way to "repair" them is to iterate all the `a`, `img`, `iframe`, `link`, `script` (and may be `object`, `form`, `applet`, `input`, ...) elements and update their relative urls (`href`, `src` attributes etc)?

Comment: `base` tag should always be the first child of `head` tag. `base` tag always applies to **all** relative urls on the page.

Comment: @zer00ne could you elaborate the "should" bit? It worked being appended as the last child (using `innerHTML`). I'll probably test the behaviour of `img` and `iframe` to see how they react to change of `base` and if changing `base` on mouseover of the container will change those and "fix" links.

Comment: [*"A base element, if it has an href attribute, must come before any other elements in the tree that have attributes defined as taking URLs, except the html element (its manifest attribute isn't affected by base elements)."*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/document-metadata#the-base-element)